# Why does vue ui / npm not let me update certain packages to latest?

Tags: vue.js, npm, package, vue-cli

Im using Vue CLI, which comes with the command `vue ui` to allow me to update the npm packages. I got the following screen:

[image]

I would like to understand:

1. The reason I cannot update to the latest versions (v4.0.5)
2. How can I can update to a later version, which I presume will contain improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You can update all dependencies and plugins via VueUI, by clicking on three dot icon (highlighted in yellow)

[VueUI - Project dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdoFS.png)

[Project plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxnTR.png)

If any of the dependencies or plugins fail to update, an error will be shown in the command prompt window you used to get the VueUI up and running on your machine. If you see errors, I recommend updating each one individually as it might pin point which one is giving problems.

Sorry for not embedding the images, I'm new and need to have at least 10 reputation to post an image

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit your package to your repository first to see the latest update in vue ui